# SharePoint Online (Modern View) Customisation (List forms - NewForm.aspx etc)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to customise SharePoint Online List Form (Like NewForm.aspx).

1. When user Click on New item in List , then automatically current site should be filled with current site title.
2. When user Click on New item in List and then type project in the text box, as per project name other details should be filled automatically from the Project master list data.

Note :-  I am using SharePoint online (Modern View).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

for SharePoint Online modern lists you should be looking at using PowerApps to modify the existing list forms. There is a quick guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form.